# What is the best way to create a COM component today?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, com, atl

I want to create a deskband COM object for my pet project. I don't have any experience with COM and a quick search revealed that ATL will simplify things. I was wondering if there are any better ways to create a COM component today. Better in the sense less boiler plate, use of C# instead of C++ and any other things you may think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If deploying or relying on a .NET framework installation on the client machine is not an issue for you, than C# is much easier than C++ (although you will probably have to redeclare interfaces, IID, etc... in C#, using [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P/Invoke)). If reducing dependencies is an issue, than C++ with ATL is better.

Answer (score 2):

Just create it in C# and expose as a COM component, see this guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I would consider C++/ATL is if I were connecting to any C/C++ libraries.  Other than than I can't think of a strong reason to use C++ over C# (assuming your skill level is equivalent in both).

Comment: When .NET was first all the rage, Microsoft advocated using it for everything including Shell Extensions and such.  They no longer do so and recommend native code for shell extensions and such. I am guessing that the guy's deskband object is close enough to a shell extension that he probably wouldn't want to use .NET.  In that case, ATL is probably the best way for writing one with native code.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson I agree and that's why I've started to do in C++. I could have accepted this as answer if you didn't posted as comment.

Answer (score -1):

I can only recommend C++ in conjunction with Microsoft's ATL library.

I used some code generation tool written in C++ that helped me to get rid of quite a lot of boilerplate code. This tool generated code that produced more C++ friendly interfaces (like the code that gets generated in the tlh/tli files when you #import a type library in Visual Studio. My code generator produces similar code, only for COM servers.

If you are interested, send a mail to DerTopper at web dot de. Put something like "COM code generator" in the subject line, so that you won't fall through my spam filter.

Regards,
Stuart